# force pip to build from source (tar.gz), not the wheel (.whl)

Tags: python, pip

When installing a package with `pip`, if available it picks the wheel for fast installation. I, however, would like to force pip to install a package from the source `.tar.gz` file.(This is to make sure that it links against the correct third-party system libraries.

(If it plays any role, this is about [h5py](https://pypi.org/project/h5py/#files).)

Any hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a `.tar.gz` file you can simply install it with `pip`:

```
pip install foobar.tar.gz
```

Also, see `pip` option `--no-binary` in the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-no-binary). Use `:all:` to force compilation of all packages, or specify a list of packages to compile.

```
pip install --no-binary :all: foobar
pip install --no-binary numpy,scipy foobar
```

To install `h5py` from sources do

```
pip install --no-binary h5py h5py
```

This will still use wheels for all other packages that might be installed as a dependency.